# .bundle in iPhone application

Tags: ios, swift, bundle

Can a .bundle file have a complete iOS application within the bundle? .bundle will be made as target and used in a different Xcode project in the same workspace. Is this possible? Nib files available in the bundle will also be loaded in the Xcode project. Please let me know the possibility.

Comment: Why not just use a Framework target? You can put bundles in it, return virtually anything you wish, and share among as many Xcode projects as needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible because bundles are one way of packaging executable codes. 
Detailed information is provided here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1